# Redirection In Some Cases Only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-v4

I have implemented Private Routing like this. If a token is present in the localStorage, private routes can be accessed. If not, we should redirect to the /404 page:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
const PrivateRoute = ({component, isAuthenticated, ...rest}: any) => {
  const routeComponent = (props: any) => (
      isAuthenticated
          ? React.createElement(component, props)
          : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/404'}}/>
  );
  return <Route {...rest} render={routeComponent}/>;
};
```

But I am also using redirection in my LoginPage.

I want that if login is unsuccessful, the error message from `ShowError()` is shown. Instead of redirecting. This was working properly before I added the redirection. If the login is successful, I should go to /panel. However, right now, if the login is unsuccessful, I just go to /404. Instead of showing the error message. How can I fix this?

Login Screen:

```
function LoginPage (){
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  }); 

 const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
function ShowError(){
  if (!localStorage.getItem('token'))
  {
    console.log('Login Not Successful');
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={colortheme}>
    <Typography color='primary'>
      Login Unsuccessful
      </Typography>
      </ThemeProvider>)
  }
}

function FormSubmitted(){
  setSubmitted(true);
}

function RedirectionToPanel(){
  if(submitted && localStorage.getItem('token')){
    return <Redirect to='/panel'/>
  }
}

  function submitForm(LoginMutation: any) {
    const { email, password } = state;
    if(email && password){
      LoginMutation({
        variables: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
    })
    .catch(console.log)
    }
  }

    return (
      <Mutation mutation={LoginMutation}>
        {(LoginMutation: any) => (
          <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div style={{
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
              <Avatar>
                <LockOutlinedIcon />
              </Avatar>
              <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                Sign in
              </Typography>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    actions.setSubmitting(false);
                  }, 1000);
                }}
                validationSchema={schema}
              >
                {props => {
                  const {
                    values: { email, password },
                    errors,
                    touched,
                    handleChange,
                    isValid,
                    setFieldTouched
                  } = props;
                  const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
                    e.persist();                
                    handleChange(e);
                    setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
                    setState( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   [name]: e.target.value }));  
                  };
                  return (
                    <form style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                    onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                    submitForm(LoginMutation);FormSubmitted();RedirectionToPanel()}}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="email"
                        fullWidth
                        name="email"
                        helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                        error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                        label="Email"     
                        value={email}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        fullWidth
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ""}
                        error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "password")}
                      /> 
                      {submitted && ShowError()}

                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                        label="Remember me"
                      />
                      <br />
                      <Button className='button-center'
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={!isValid || !email || !password}
                        // onClick={handleOpen}
                        style={{
                          background: '#6c74cc',
                          borderRadius: 3,
                          border: 0,
                          color: 'white',
                          height: 48,
                          padding: '0 30px'
                        }}
                      >                       
                        Submit</Button>
                      <br></br>
                      <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs>
                    </form>
                  )
                }}
              </Formik>
            </div>
            {submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}
          </Container>
          )
        }
      </Mutation>
    );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

**Edit::**

I tried using this too:

```
  if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
    return <Redirect to='/panel'/>
  }
});
```

but it gives me an error on the arrow that:

```
Argument of type '() => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => void | undefined)'.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => void | undefined)'.
      Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '() => void | undefined'.
        Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(): void | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line at the end of the container.

```
{submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}
```

as it doesn't make sense to be there.
also, adjust the submit method to execute functions correctly.

```
function submitForm(LoginMutation: any) {
   const { email, password } = state;
   return LoginMutation({
     variables: {
       email,
       password,
     },
   }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
   }).catch(console.error);
}
```

with promise being returned from the submitForm method, you can do the following.

```
onSubmit={e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   submitForm(LoginMutation).then((res: any) => {
      RedirectionToPanel();
      FormSubmitted();
   });
}}
```

Comment: If I remove that line, the redirection doesn't happen when the token is present as well

Comment: it also won't be executed cause the value of `submitted` is always false when the component gets mounted. remove the `submitted` from the `if` statement of the method `RedirectionToPanel` then call it (so it directs to the `panel` if there is token) via `useEffect` or change the component to `React.Component` you have many methods there and it became reasonable to use.

Comment: Also, I get an error saying that ```Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)```on ```.then```

Comment: Could you maybe give an example of how I could use useEffect here? Haven't had a chance to use it before

Comment: I updated the question with how I tried using UseEffect()